# linking two optionbuttons with single combo box for different rowsource

Tags: excel, combobox, vbe, radio-button, vba

I have three sheets "display", "whole_list", "loose_list". I just draws one combo box and 2 optionbutton in display sheet.

I have 200 item list in whole_list and loose_list. I wish to do that when I click on the optionbutton1 combo box will show me the list from whole_list. If I click on the optionbutton2 it will show me the list from loose_list.

Can someone guide me to create that what I mentioned above?

Comment: Please re-frame your post as a question and also provide the code you have problems with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have time to spare and thought i would show you a way with Forms controls.

This assumes `display` tab has the Form combobox and the two Form option buttons.

In `whole_list` set up a named range called `whole_list` covering your list of 200 items e.g. `A1:A200` and do the same thing for `loose_list`.

In a `standard module` enter the following:

```
Option Explicit
Dim myList As Variant

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()

   mylist = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("whole_list").Range("whole_list").Value

   PopulateComboBox myList

End Sub


Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()

   mylist = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("loose_list").Range("loose_list").Value

   PopulateComboBox myList

End Sub

Private Sub PopulateComboBox(myList As Variant)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws as Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.worksheets("display")

    Dim myDropDown As DropDown

    Set myDropDown = ws.Shapes("Drop Down 1").OLEFormat.Object
    myDropDown.List = myList

End Sub
```

Make sure the object and sheet names match up. You can check the combobox and option button names by highlighting them and then checking the `Name box` at the top left of the sheet.

Right click each Option Button and choose `assign macro` and associate each button with the correct `OptionButton` click sub.

**If your objects are `ActiveX`:**

In the worksheet code window  containing your `ActiveX` objects e.g. `display` ,
if you right click on the tab and select `view code`,  it will bring up the code window and enter the following (Assuming you have the two named ranges as before)

```
Option Explicit
Public myList As Variant

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()

   mylist = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("whole_list").Range("whole_list").Value

   Me.ComboBox1.List = myList

End Sub


Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()

   mylist = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("loose_list").Range("loose_list").Value

   Me.ComboBox1.List = myList

End Sub
```

No additional procedure needed and no right click and assigning of macros. The `Me` part says take the reference of the sheet the code is in. If you have `Option Explicit`, at the top of the worksheet code, then you should receive a prompt which includes the name of your combobox, amongst the options available, but you can also get it from the `Name Box` in the sheet. Here, my combobox is called `Combobox1`.

Comment: hi, thanks for ur time and answer. I did what u said. I have some issues.
1.optionbutton is ActiveX control where can I assign macro?

2. Set myDropDown = ws.Shapes("Drop Down 1").OLEFormat.object

this line I didn't understand and also had debug error "the item with the specified name wasn't found"

pls fix this error. maybe I am closer to finish this.

thank you!

Comment: OptionButton1, OptionButton2,
ComboBox1

Comment: thank u guys! u r amazing. it works well.